# Cannot connect Hyper-V VM Network Adapter to a Hyper-V Switch via WMI in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am having quite some difficulty connecting a specific, existing network adapter to an existing switch.  I can create a new network adapter and connect it to my VM through several examples posted online but cannot make that extra step.  The following function finds my network adapter and executes without error, but does not otherwise make the connection.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
**EDIT: Solved, see code below.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
    public static void ConnectInterfaceToSwitch(string VmName, string networkInterfaceName, string switchName)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\virtualization\v2");
        ManagementObject mgtSvc = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualMachineManagementService(scope);
        ManagementObject ethernetSwitch = NetworkingUtilities.FindEthernetSwitch(switchName, scope);
        ManagementObject virtualMachine = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualMachine(VmName, scope);
        ManagementObject virtualMachineSettings = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualMachineSettings(virtualMachine);
        ManagementObjectCollection portsSettings = virtualMachineSettings.GetRelated("Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPortSettingData", "Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingDataComponent", null, null, null, null, false, null);
        {                
            foreach (ManagementObject portSettings in portsSettings)
            {
                if (portSettings["ElementName"].Equals(networkInterfaceName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Adapter found: " + networkInterfaceName);
                    ManagementObjectCollection connections = portSettings.GetRelated("Msvm_EthernetPortAllocationSettingData");
                    foreach (ManagementObject connection in connections)
                    {
                        connection["HostResource"] = new string[] { ethernetSwitch.Path.Path };
                        connection["EnabledState"] = 2; // 2 means "Enabled"    
                        ManagementBaseObject inParams = mgtSvc.GetMethodParameters("ModifyResourceSettings");
                        inParams["ResourceSettings"] = new string[] { connection.GetText(TextFormat.WmiDtd20) };

                        ManagementBaseObject outParams = mgtSvc.InvokeMethod("ModifyResourceSettings", inParams, null);
                        WmiUtilities.ValidateOutput(outParams, scope);

                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Connected VM '{0}' to switch '{1}'.", VmName, switchName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```